# Confirmation and undo removing in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have got a list of simple items in RecyclerView. Using ItemTouchHelper it was very easy to implement "swipe-to-delete" behavior.

```
public class TripsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TripsAdapter.VerticalItemHolder> {
    private List<Trip> mTrips;
    private Context mContext;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    [...]

    //Let adapter know his RecyclerView. Attaching ItemTouchHelper
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new TripItemTouchHelperCallback());
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
    }

    [...]

    public class TripItemTouchHelperCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
        public  TripItemTouchHelperCallback (){
            super(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                              RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            //some "move" implementation
        }
        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
            //AND WHAT HERE?
        }
    }
}
```

It works well. However i also need to implement some undo action or confirmation. What is the best way to do this?

First question is how to insert another view in place of removed with confirmation dialog? And how to restore swiped item, if user chooses to undo removing?

Comment: "What is the best way to do this?" -- [an undo bar](https://github.com/soarcn/UndoBar) or snackbar. "And how to restore swiped item, if user chooses to undo removing?" -- update your model, then call the appropriate `notify...()` method on the `RecyclerView.Adapter` to indicate what changed in your model.

Answer (score 24):

I agree with @Gabor that it is better to soft delete the items and show the undo button.

However I'm using Snackbar for showing the UNDO. It was easier to implement for me.

I'm passing the Adapter and the RecyclerView instance to my ItemTouchHelper callback. My onSwiped is simple and most of the work is done by adapter.

Here is my code (**edited 2016/01/10**):

```
@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    mAdapter.onItemRemove(viewHolder, mRecyclerView);
}
```

The onItemRemove methos of the adapter is:

```
   public void onItemRemove(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    final int adapterPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    final Photo mPhoto = photos.get(adapterPosition);
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
            .make(recyclerView, "PHOTO REMOVED", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int mAdapterPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                    photos.add(mAdapterPosition, mPhoto);
                    notifyItemInserted(mAdapterPosition);
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapterPosition);
                    photosToDelete.remove(mPhoto);
                }
            });
    snackbar.show();
    photos.remove(adapterPosition);
    notifyItemRemoved(adapterPosition);
    photosToDelete.add(mPhoto);
}
```

The photosToDelete is an ArrayList field of myAdapter. I'm doing the real delete of those items in onPause() method of the recyclerView host fragment.

Note **edit 2016/01/10**:

- changed hard-coded position as @Sourabh suggested in comments
- for the complete example of adapter and fragment with RV see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jirivrany/f1f177b7bbc187e8f980)

Comment: I liked you idea. Some apps show undo button on background after swiping foreground view. But it's very difficult to implement that. Your approach is enough. There are more important things to focus.

Comment: On a side note, instead of using a hard coded position, you should use ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition

Comment: @Sourabh I'm not sure if I get your point. I'm using the getAdapterPosition in the onSwiped method. In this method I call the method of the adapter, with the position as argument. Where is the hard coded position?

Comment: Here: `photos.add(adapterPosition, mPhoto);`. Before clicking `Undo`, the adapter position might change, you should pass holder to `onItemRemove()`

Comment: @JikraV. nice approach but can you explain little more,because i am trying to implement but getting error.Here what is mRecyclerView, Photo
Please explain on the basis of example swipe to remove and drag& drop

Comment: @Sourabh - now I see :) You are right. I changed the example as you suggested.

Comment: @RiteshMathur - mRecyclerView is the instance of RecyclerView passed to adapter when the adapter is created. I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but it works for me. To be more detailed I created a gist with more code for you - https://gist.github.com/jirivrany/f1f177b7bbc187e8f980 hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but your method is throwing `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index -1, size is 4`

Comment: @Ozuf - it works for me ;-) Which line throws this in your code?

Comment: this line `int mAdapterPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();` I modified your answer to suit my purpose, please can you confirm if it's working for you?

Comment: @Ozuf - there was a mistake in code example. The mAdapterPostition should be declared final. I forgot to correct the answer here. Thanks for pointing this out. The gist with full example should be correct.

Comment: @JirkaV Thanks. It was very helpful. I guess you should put  `final int mAdapterPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();` outside the onClickListener. Just after SnackBar declaration to avoid IndexOutOfBoundsException. Regards.

Answer (score 14):

The usual approach is not to delete the item immediately upon swipe. Put up a message (it could be a snackbar or, as in Gmail, a message overlaying the item just swiped) and provide both a timeout and an undo button for the message.

If the user presses the undo button while the message is visible, you simply dismiss the message and return to normal processing. Delete the actual item only if the timeout elapses without the user pressing the undo button.

Basically, something along these lines:

```
@Override
public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
  final View undo = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.undo);
  if (undo != null) {
    // optional: tapping the message dismisses immediately
    TextView text = (TextView) viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.undo_text);
    text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        callbacks.onDismiss(recyclerView, viewHolder, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
      }
    });

    TextView button = (TextView) viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.undo_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
        undo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
    });

    undo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    undo.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        if (undo.isShown())
          callbacks.onDismiss(recyclerView, viewHolder, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
      }
    }, UNDO_DELAY);
  }
}
```

This supposes the existence of an `undo` layout in the item viewholder, normally invisible, with two items, a text (saying *Deleted* or similar) and an *Undo* button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  ...

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/undo"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:paddingRight="10dp"
      android:visibility="gone">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/undo_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:text="Deleted"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/undo_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|end"
        android:text="UNDO"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Tapping the button simply removes the message. Optionally, tapping the text confirms the deletion and deletes the item immediately by calling the appropriate callback in your code. Don't forget to call back to your adapter's `notifyItemRemoved()`:

```
public void onDismiss(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
  //TODO delete the actual item in your data source
  adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Comment: Hi what is callbacks in adapter class?

Comment: A listener interface, this is the usual way to send an event in Android (all system listeners like OnClickListener work that way). But it can be any call you need to make the actual deletion.

Comment: I've tried to implement that solution but when showing the undo button, any click calls the onSwiped() method again instead of the onClick(). It's like any touch event on the undo view is interpreted as a swipe as long as the row is not fully deleted. Any ideas?

Comment: Before you actually do your swiping work in `onSwiped()`, you could simply hide the whole undo layout with its `setVisibility()`.

Comment: It does in my app... :-)

Comment: @Gabor could you please explain in detail because code is not working properly when i swipped two times then undo button come in down sode

Answer (score 4):

I tried [JirkaV's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34164381/6181476), but it was throwing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I was able to modify his solution to work for me. Please try it and let me know if you run into problems.

```
 @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        final int adapterPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        final BookItem bookItem = mBookItems.get(adapterPosition); //mBookItems is an arraylist of mBookAdpater;
        snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(mRecyclerView, R.string.item_removed, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction(R.string.undo, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        mBookItems.add(adapterPosition, bookItem);
                        mBookAdapter.notifyItemInserted(adapterPosition); //mBookAdapter is my Adapter class
                        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapterPosition);
                    }
                })
                .setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                        super.onDismissed(snackbar, event);
                        Log.d(TAG, "SnackBar dismissed");
                        if (event != DISMISS_EVENT_ACTION) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "SnackBar not dismissed by click event");
                            //In my case I doing a database transaction. The items are only deleted from the database if the snackbar is not dismissed by click the UNDO button

                            mDatabase = mBookHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                            String whereClause = "_id" + "=?";
                            String[] whereArgs = new String[]{
                                    String.valueOf(bookItem.getDatabaseId())
                            };
                            mDatabase.delete(BookDbSchema.BookEntry.NAME, whereClause, whereArgs);
                            mDatabase.close();
                        }
                    }
                });
        snackbar.show();
        mBookItems.remove(adapterPosition);
        mBookAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(adapterPosition);
    }
```

### How it works

When the user swipes, a snackbar is shown and the item is removed from the dataset, hence this:

```
snackbar.show();
BookItems.remove(adapterPosition);
mBookAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(adapterPosition);
```

Since the data used in populating the recyclerView is from an SQL database,  the swiped item is not removed from the database at this point.

When the user clicks on the "UNDO" button, the swiped item is simply brought back and the recyclerView scrolls to the position of the just re-added item. Hence this:

```
 mBookItems.add(adapterPosition, bookItem);
 mBookAdapter.notifyItemInserted(adapterPosition); 
 mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapterPosition);
```

Then when the snackbar dismisses, I checked if the snackbar was dismissed by the user clicking on the "UNDO" button. If no, I delete the item from the database at this point.

Probably there are performance issues with this solution, I haven''t found any. Please if you notice any, drop your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out much simpler way to do a deletion confirmation dialog working:

```
@Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            int itemPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

            new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this)
                    .setMessage("Do you want to delete: \"" + mRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemAtPosition(itemPosition).getName() + "\"?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Delete", (dialog, which) -> mYourActivityViewModel.removeItem(itemPosition))
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> mRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemChanged(itemPosition))
                    .setOnCancelListener(dialogInterface -> mRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemChanged(itemPosition))
                    .create().show();
        }
```

Note that:

- deletion is delegated to *ViewModel* which updates the *mRecyclerViewAdapter* upon success.
- for the item to "return" you just have to call *mRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemChanged*
- *cancelListener* and *negativeButtonListener* perform the same thing. You can opt to use .setCanclable(false) if you don't want the user to tap outside the dialog