# remove and undo in RecyclerView with CursorRecyclerAdatper

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My recyclerview adapter is loaded with cursor which query data from the local database.

When user click on the delete button in the Viewholder layout, then it will delete from the recycler view, but not yet from the database until the snackbar timeout.

This button listener is in CustomRecyclerAdapter

```
Button deleteButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    }
});
```

How to temporarily removed from the cursor and then add back? Currently, after remove animation, call onBindViewHolder, the data is backed again because it is in the cursor.

I check this post. But this is the arraylist. 
[Confirmation and undo removing in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850494/confirmation-and-undo-removing-in-recyclerview)

How can i temporarily removed from the cursor before it is actually delete from the database?

Or i can only add a delete flag to the database column and requery? After timeout, then delete from the database. If undo, then clear this flag and requery.

Answer (score 0):

Without impacting on database and with need to change to arraylist. I use to query the items that are not the delete id list. It solved my requirement.

```
int argCount = deleteRowsId.size();
if (argCount > 0) {
    String[] selectionArgs = deleteRowsId.toArray(new String[0]);
    StringBuilder inList = new StringBuilder(argCount * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < argCount; i++) {
         if (i > 0) {
             inList.append(",");
         }
             inList.append("?");
    }

    String selection = Contacts._ID + " NOT IN (" + inList.toString() + ")";

    return new CursorLoader(this.getContext(), baseUri, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, limit);}
```