# Cancel the action of deleting of a recyclerview item with snackbar

Tags: android, android-snackbar

That's my deletion code for recyclerview items.

```
viewHolder.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        context.getContentResolver().delete(ContractParaGastos.CONTENT_URI,ContractParaGastos.Columnas.MONTO + " = ?", new String[]{nom});
        SyncAdapter.sincronizarAhora(context, true);
    }
});
```

I would like to know how to implement a cancel function in a snackbar.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't delete the item. You could just remove it from the recyclerview, but still store it. Then you can put up a snackbar with the confirmation message. If the user clicks **Cancel** then you could just put the item into the  recyclerview again.

So you could basically have a view called undo which gets replaced with the "deleted" item:

```
View undo = yourView;
```

So if the user decides to cancel his operation just get the view from your undo, put it into the RecyclerView and set your undo view to null.

There is a great explanation on this page: [Confirmation and undo removing in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850494/confirmation-and-undo-removing-in-recyclerview/32551039#32551039)

Comment: i looked at it but does not fit my needs since i do not use onswiped

Comment: @Mavis That makes no difference. The principle is still the same.